# Hyper-V BSDO since Windows 10 last 2 builds - systematic crashes can't find the reason

Tags: windows-10, hyper-v, crash-dumps, hal, bsod

Whenever I turn Hyper-v machines windows crashes, if I shutdown or pause windows does not crash.
Please help… I am getting crazy and about to revert my virtual machines back to VMware… this is unbarable, since version 1809 ~ 1903 that this started to happen … with 1903 is in a few minutes of hyperv startup.

```
Microsoft (R) Windows Debugger Version 10.0.19528.1000 AMD64
Copyright (c) Microsoft Corporation. All rights reserved.

Loading Dump File [C:\Windows\MEMORY.DMP]
Kernel Bitmap Dump File: Full address space is available


************* Path validation summary **************
Response                         Time (ms)     Location
Deferred                                       srv*
Symbol search path is: srv*
Executable search path is: 
Windows 10 Kernel Version 18362 MP (8 procs) Free x64
Product: WinNt, suite: TerminalServer SingleUserTS
18362.1.amd64fre.19h1_release.190318-1202
Machine Name:
Kernel base = 0xfffff804`71000000 PsLoadedModuleList = 0xfffff804`71448190
Debug session time: Tue Feb 18 21:30:51.323 2020 (UTC + 0:00)
System Uptime: 0 days 5:54:41.082
Loading Kernel Symbols
...............................................................
................................................................
................................................................
.............
Loading User Symbols

Loading unloaded module list
..............
For analysis of this file, run !analyze -v
nt!KeBugCheckEx:
fffff804`711c1510 48894c2408      mov     qword ptr [rsp+8],rcx ss:0018:fffff804`75500c70=00000000000001ca
0: kd> !analyze -v
*******************************************************************************
*                                                                             *
*                        Bugcheck Analysis                                    *
*                                                                             *
*******************************************************************************

SYNTHETIC_WATCHDOG_TIMEOUT (1ca)
A system wide watchdog has expired. This indicates that the system
is hung and not processing timer ticks.
Arguments:
Arg1: 00000000133922d2, The time since the watchdog was last reset, in interrupt time.
Arg2: 00000031d2b297f6, The current interrupt time.
Arg3: 00000031d2b5a756, The current QPC timestamp.
Arg4: 0000000000000003, The index of the clock processor.

Debugging Details:
------------------


KEY_VALUES_STRING: 1

    Key  : Analysis.CPU.Sec
    Value: 5

    Key  : Analysis.DebugAnalysisProvider.CPP
    Value: Create: 8007007e on STATIC

    Key  : Analysis.DebugData
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.DebugModel
    Value: CreateObject

    Key  : Analysis.Elapsed.Sec
    Value: 5

    Key  : Analysis.Memory.CommitPeak.Mb
    Value: 63

    Key  : Analysis.System
    Value: CreateObject


ADDITIONAL_XML: 1

BUGCHECK_CODE:  1ca

BUGCHECK_P1: 133922d2

BUGCHECK_P2: 31d2b297f6

BUGCHECK_P3: 31d2b5a756

BUGCHECK_P4: 3

PROCESS_NAME:  System

BAD_STACK_POINTER:  fffff80475500c68

STACK_TEXT:  
fffff804`75500c68 fffff804`71aeaa55 : 00000000`000001ca 00000000`133922d2 00000031`d2b297f6 00000031`d2b5a756 : nt!KeBugCheckEx
fffff804`75500c70 fffff804`71ad4dec : 00000031`d2b5a756 00000000`00000001 fffff804`71354614 00000000`00000082 : hal!HalpWatchdogCheckPreResetNMI+0xd5
fffff804`75500cb0 fffff804`712a4ceb : 00000000`00000001 00000031`d2b480d4 fffff804`6da02180 fffff804`712b5ff0 : hal!HalpPreprocessNmi+0x11e5c
fffff804`75500ce0 fffff804`711ccb42 : 00000000`00000001 fffff804`75500ef0 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiProcessNMI+0xcb
fffff804`75500d30 fffff804`711cc914 : 00000000`00000001 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KxNmiInterrupt+0x82
fffff804`75500e70 fffff804`71304a2e : 00000000`00000000 00004e30`93efa406 00000000`00000000 00000031`d2b480d4 : nt!KiNmiInterrupt+0x214
fffff804`754e77a0 fffff804`71021e7c : fffff804`71304a50 ffffa08e`f2f18010 00000000`00000000 00000000`0000065e : nt!PpmIdleGuestExecute+0x1e
fffff804`754e77e0 fffff804`710215ce : 00000000`00000003 00000000`00000002 ffffa08e`f2f18100 00000000`00000008 : nt!PpmIdleExecuteTransition+0x70c
fffff804`754e7b00 fffff804`711c5018 : 00000000`00000000 fffff804`6da02180 ffffa08e`fc3bf080 00000000`0000087d : nt!PoIdle+0x36e
fffff804`754e7c60 00000000`00000000 : fffff804`754e8000 fffff804`754e2000 00000000`00000000 00000000`00000000 : nt!KiIdleLoop+0x48


SYMBOL_NAME:  nt!KiProcessNMI+cb

MODULE_NAME: nt

IMAGE_NAME:  ntkrnlmp.exe

STACK_COMMAND:  .thread ; .cxr ; kb

BUCKET_ID_FUNC_OFFSET:  cb

FAILURE_BUCKET_ID:  0x1CA_STACKPTR_ERROR_nt!KiProcessNMI

OS_VERSION:  10.0.18362.1

BUILDLAB_STR:  19h1_release

OSPLATFORM_TYPE:  x64

OSNAME:  Windows 10

FAILURE_ID_HASH:  {09a889cd-f940-6da5-9668-0c0c98a7d643}
```

Comment: The stack trace for this thread doesn't show a smoking gun as to what module triggered expired the watchdog `HalpWatchdogCheckPreResetNMI`. My best theory is some updated driver for some hardware component is holding onto resources longer than it should causing a hang leading to bug check.

Comment: Thank you Mike, I run the driver VERIFY and the minidump data was this,

Comment: One thing is certain, whenever vm machines are turn off or paused, there are no crashes. I am very uncertain to what might cause this, since every time a Microsoft update and a Nvidia driver update are deployed are the crucial moments for this crashes to start to happen, I already unninstall'd all drivers, did a fresh windows install and every time the vm machines are turn on the crash happens (after windows updates to the mentioned versions) Hyper-v ON=crash I am really having a hard time to figure out why...

Comment: This is sounding more of a backwards compatibility issue between the VM image and the host. I recommend allowing full dumps to be collected on the machine, so they can be sent to Microsoft. Minidumps might not have all the details as to what happened.

Comment: Oh !! Thank you, that is a prism that I haven't considered… Kind regards.

Comment: All the VM are at version 9, windows version changes also updated VM's.

Comment: I have a windows 2008 r2 running an AD, a windows 2012 r2 running SQL and 2012 r2 running a SharePoint server 2016.
Is it possible that the 2008 r2 is creating the issues !? Since Microsoft states that 2008 r2 are no longer supported architectures are no longer supported as guests.

Comment: @NunoJorge had you a chance to somehow fix it? I experience the same issue and about to getting crazy of inability to do anything with it